# parsing json into flutter List<dynamic> to Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, dio, cubit

Hello I want to parse Json and I faced this issue what's wrong please help 
the error was 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' 
**Model**

```
class CategoriesModel {
  CategoriesModel({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.price,
    this.description,
    this.image,
  });

  int? id;
  String? title;
  double? price;
  String? description;
  String? image;

  factory CategoriesModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CategoriesModel(
      id: json["id"],
      title: json["title"],
      price: json["price"].toDouble(),
      description: json["description"],
      image: json["image"],
    );
  }


  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "price": price,
    "description": description,
    "image": image,
  };
}
```

in **cubit** I did this (AppCubit.dart)

```
CategoriesModel? categoriesModel ;

   getCategories(){
    emit(OnLoadingCategoriesState());
    DioHelper.getData(pathUrl: "products").then((value){
      categoriesModel = CategoriesModel.fromJson(value.data);
      // catList =  (value.data as List)
      //     .map((x) => CategoriesModel.fromJson(x))
      //     .toList();
      // print(catList.length);

      emit(OnSuccessCategoriesState());
    }).catchError((error){
      emit(OnCatchErrorCategoriesState(error.toString()));
      print(error.toString());
    });
  }
```

in **Dio** Helper I did general function to use it

```
  static Future<Response> getData({required pathUrl})async{
   return await dio.get(pathUrl);
  }
```

and this is small data from **json**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops",
    "price": 109.95,
    "description": "Your perfect pack for everyday use and walks in the forest. Stash your laptop (up to 15 inches) in the padded sleeve, your everyday",
    "category": "men's clothing",
    "image": "https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Mens Casual Premium Slim Fit T-Shirts ",
    "price": 22.3,
    "description": "Slim-fitting style, contrast raglan long sleeve, three-button henley placket, light weight & soft fabric for breathable and comfortable wearing. And Solid stitched shirts with round neck made for durability and a great fit for casual fashion wear and diehard baseball fans. The Henley style round neckline includes a three-button placket.",
    "category": "men's clothing",
    "image": "https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71-3HjGNDUL._AC_SY879._SX._UX._SY._UY_.jpg"
  },
]
```

finally this is error that was appeared to me

```
I/flutter (31455): onChange -- AppCubit, Change { currentState: Instance of 'OnLoadingCategoriesState', nextState: Instance of 'OnCatchErrorCategoriesState' }
I/flutter (31455): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

any help I'll appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CategoriesModel.fromJson` is expecting the type `Map<String, dynamic>` but the json snippet shows that the response is a `List`.

Update the `.then` function to handle the list and create the `CategoriesModel` from each item in the `List`, Similar to the code that is commented out in the snippet above.

```dart
 DioHelper.getData(pathUrl: "products").then((List values) {
     values.map((e) => CategoriesModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response but there the error now : The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Response'.

Comment: Update the `getData` function check the `Response` and return the data from the response.

Comment: sorry Rohan I can't get you but when return response it was List<key,value> array of objects .. thanks for your help

Comment: do you mean Map<String, dynamic>?

Comment: That the issue i covered in the answer above.